# What class does Qt designer use to edit the properties of UI elements?

Tags: qt5, qt-designer

At the moment I'm writing a tool to extract parts of frames of mp4-video files. You draw rectangles on the video and the tool extracts .png-images at regular intervals. Now I want to give the user the ability to edit the properties of individual rectangles they have drawn on the video (exact position, frequency of frame extraction, time frame, etc.). I like the approach that QtDesigner takes for editing ui elements. You can see what I mean in this screenshot i found on the internet

[image]

The yellow and green table contains name value pairs for the different properties of the selected ui element. The table is devided into section depending on what class the property was inherented from. In the Screenshot the green part is inherented from MarbleWidget. The yellow part is inherented form a different class. I want each division to refer to a different rectangle and the color to match the colour the rectangle is drawn in on the screen.

I've tried using QTreeView, QTableView, QToolBox and QTableWidget but none of these - to my knowledge - offer putting QWidgets in the "value" part of the table. In the screenshot you can see tick boxes for example. In my case I would want to use a range slider. Does anyone know what class is used to Implement this table?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesignerpropertyeditorinterface.html#details

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it difficult to use the designer classes in a normal application.

See [qtpropertybrowser](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtpropertybrowser) for a properties editor.

See [setIndexWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) for a static widget.  As it says, use QItemDelegate for dynamic widgets.  Note that the specific item subclasses have their own methods like QTableWidget.setCellWidget.